# Java Scheduler Job/Task/Thread per entry in the database table

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, scheduler

I want a scheduler that creates a job/task/thread per entry in my database table.
Further, I want a mechanism to start, pause, stop, and restart each job without affecting the other jobs/tasks/threads. At any moment, I should be able to create a new job or delete one.

I am planning to handle all the job related operations mentioned above through a web application hosted on tomcat server.

Which java scheduler should I opt for and how do I start with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

In Quartz I would suggest to use JDBJobStore, it allows you to store your jobs in database.

Coming to creating jobs per entry in DB, you can one JobcreatorFactory which reads entry from your DB and you can create job for that and that job will be stored in DB.

Ideally its better to have separate job class(extends JOB) for every job you want to create. But as you want to create jobs dynamically, you can have general job class which takes context of that job and perform respective operation based on the context inside overridden method og your general job class.

Using Quartz its possible to start, stop, pause your jobs without affecting other jobs.

Hope this helps !